# Is it possible to edit the resources of an .NET executable during runtime?

Tags: .net, resources, runtime, edit

I am working on a project to keep all my passwords in safe. I don't want to use another file to keep the passwords, I want it to be stand-alone. Thus, on runtime (let's say when I press apply button or on FormClosing event etc...) I need to edit the resources that will be keeping encrypted passwords. Is it possible and if so how? If not possible, what are the best alternatives? Btw, I don't want to use registry either since it would kill portability.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: By resources I mean embeded ones.

Edit: After Jason's answer, I need to change the question a little bit; is there any way to write anything to a running executable itself?

Comment: What platforms do you want this to work on? I imagine the UAC and any anti-virus software will not take very kindly to this sort of thing.

Comment: When you say "resources", do you mean an external file e.g. txt, or an actual .resx file? Just to be clear :)

Comment: Windows. I would prefer WinXP and later but just Win7 is ok too.

Comment: I wonder if there could be a better method for storing passwords ..

Comment: Btw, UAC will not be a problem in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292) shows how to access an embedded resources inside an assembly using a stream. Could give you enough of a start on how to edit the passwords resource that you mention.

EDIT;
Ah, even better:

[How to read embedded resource text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file)

EDIT:

Just use a [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx) e.g.

```
using (Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                               .GetManifestResourceStream("file1.txt"))
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream))
{
    sw.Write("This is a test");
}
```

EDIT:

OK, looks like a dead end:

[How To Read, Then Write To An Embedded Resource In C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736267/how-to-read-then-write-to-an-embedded-resource-in-c-sharp)

> Embedded resources are compiled into your assembly, you can't edit
>   them.

Comment: They don't seem to show me how to write to an embeded resource, they show only the reading part :(

Comment: I tried it. It throws an exception: System.ArgumentException: Stream was not writable.

Comment: Well that's sad. So I will copy paste the question in the thread you pointed :) "Do you know if there's any way to write to a resource that's part of the program without having the data in a seperate file?"