# How can I set a different string value for the value field in a resource file in c# programatically?

Tags: c#

Here is the code how I am getting the string value from the resource file

```
System.Resources.ResourceManager rsMgr = new System.Resources.ResourceManager("DemoResourceLocalization.ErrorMessageResource"
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
string value = rsMgr.GetString("PersonName");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3736293/1380061

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading string from resource file and editing it programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20772976/reading-string-from-resource-file-and-editing-it-programmatically)

Comment: Embedded resources are embedded and are readonly, The thing you can have, is different values for different cultures that you can read.

Comment: No I tried .But its not working @FredrikRedin

Comment: No I tried .But its not working @Nikita

Comment: did you read the answer there ! it tells you why it does not work, why it shouldn't & what is the alternative.

Comment: yup!! I understood but the proper implementation, I not able to figure out@Nikita

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the resources programmatically, you should work either with the `.resx` files directly or use some custom writable resource database.

You can use the `ResXResourceReader` and `ResXResourceWriter` classes to read the strings into a dictionary and at the end write them back into a new `.resx` file.

```
public static class DynamicResourceManager
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> dictionary;

    // are there any changes
    private static bool isDirty = false;

    // The current language of the resources to manage
    private static CultureInfo activeLanguage = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;

    public static CultureInfo ActiveLanguage
    {
        get { return activeLanguage; }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("value");

            if (!activeLanguage.Equals(value))
            {
                if (isDirty)
                    SaveDictionary();

                activeLanguage = value;
                LoadDictionary();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void LoadDictionary()
    {
        // The ResourceManager is case-insensitive so we are, too
        if (dictionary == null)
             dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        else
            dictionary.Clear();

        string file = GetFileName();
        if (!File.Exists(file))
            return;

        using (IResourceReader reader = new ResXResourceReader(file))
        {
            foreach (DictionaryEntry item in reader)
            {
                string value = item.Value as string;
                if (value != null)
                    dictionary.Add(item.Key.ToString(), value);
            }
        }
    }

    // this should be called explicitly when you exit the application, but
    // is called automatically when ActiveLanguage is changed
    public static void SaveDictionary()
    {
        if (!isDirty)
            return;

        string file = GetFileName();
        string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);

        if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);

        using (IResourceWriter writer = new ResXResourceWriter(file))
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in dictionary)
                writer.AddResource(item.Key, item.Value);
        }

        isDirty = false;            
    }

    private static string GetFileName()
    {
        return Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), "Languages") + activeLanguage.Name + ".resx");
    }

    public static string GetString(string key)
    {
        if (key == null)
            return String.Empty;

        if (dictionary == null)
            LoadDictionary();

        string result;
        if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out result))
        {
            // entry not found in this language, adding it dynamically
            dictionary.Add("NEW:" + key, key);
            isDirty = true;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static void SetString(string key)
    {
        if (dictionary == null)
            LoadDictionary();

        dictionary[key] = value;
        isDirty = true;
    }
}
```

Incompatibilities with the `ResourceManager` class:

- Does not handle culture hierarchy (eg. en-US -> en -> Invariant).
- Ignores non-string resources

**Update 2019:**

Recently I made my libraries open source, which supports [dynamic resource management](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.CoreLibraries#dynamic-resource-management). Unlike the sample above, it does not need a reference to `System.Windows.Forms.dll` because it has its own resource reader/writer implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the solution .its working fine but on the next run of the application the updated value is displayed not at that run .Any idea how i can resolve this issue

Comment: Maybe the dictionary was not initialized because you did not change the `ActiveLanguage`. I have edited the answer. See the `dictionary` field, `GetString` and `LoadDictionary`.

Comment: And do not forget to call the public `SaveDictionary` before you exit the application.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!ONCE IT WORKS  I WILL UPDATE YOU:):)