# Read/Write JSON file in C# class library project

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

I'm working for some class library project and required to store some tiny data in a text file say JSON and need to do the read/write operations.

- This DLL will be referenced to any project in the C# development so I am unable to hard-code with the file absolute path.
- I need to do with the embed resource and I am unable to write it back. How can I achieve this write operation within the class library ?

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433171/how-to-embed-a-text-file-in-a-net-assembly) helped me to read such file content and stuck in writing it back

Comment: If the file path is going to depend on the application, why can't the library require that information from the application?  For example as a string argument on a method or constructor?  Then the application can store it however it likes, such as in a config value.

Comment: I agree!! But developing some independent module. Need to store some iteration count within the library. I can't go with config file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Read, Then Write To An Embedded Resource In C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736267/how-to-read-then-write-to-an-embedded-resource-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Short answer is that you can't write to an embedded resource -- see duplicate question for more details.

Comment: You are right @DavidCulp, But I need to read/write to file operation in that Library. Can't go with database. Any alternate way I can do file operation in that ?

Comment: Maybe you could update the question with information about what it is you want to do -- instead of just one implementation.  What is the expected result?  where is it going to be used? what restrictions do you have?  and so on.